# S3 Principal Bucket Policy Permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a cloudformation template up in an S3 bucket (the url follows the pattern but is not exactly equal to: https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/cloudform.yaml).  I need to be able to access it from CLI for a bash script.  I'd prefer that everybody in an organization (all in this single account) has access to this template but other people outside of the organization don't have access to the template.  A bucket policy I've tried looks like:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy11111111",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt111111111",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::7777777777:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    }
]
}
```

With this policy, I and a couple other people in my office are unable to access the url.  Even when I'm logged in with the root account I'm getting Access Denied.

Also, this change (only setting Principal to *) makes the bucket accessible to anybody:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy11111111",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt111111111",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Obviously the signs point to my Principal field being misconfigured.  777777777 is the replacement for the Account ID I see under the My Account page.

So, do I need to worry about this on the IAM front?  Considering that I am logged in as the root user, I'd guess I should have access to this as long as I put in a bucket policy.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Short and sweet:**

The bucket policy doesn't allow you to do what you want because of a wildcard limitation of the Principal element. Your best bet is to create an IAM group and put all IAM users into that group if they need access.

**Long version:**

Just to make it clear, any request to https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/cloudform.yaml MUST be signed and have the necessary authentication parameters or the request will be rejected with Access Denied. The only exception is if the bucket policy or the bucket ACL allows public access, but it doesn't sound like this is what you want.

When you say "everybody in an organization (all in this single account)" I assume you mean IAM users under the account who are accessing the file from the AWS console, or IAM users who are using some other code or tool (e.g. AWS CLI) to access the file.

So what it sounds like what you want is the ability to specify the Principal as

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:user/*"
}
```

since that is what the pattern would be for any IAM user under the 777777777777 account id. Unfortunately this is not allowed because no wildcard is allowed in the Principal unless you use the catch-all wildcard "*". In other words "*" is allowed, but either "prefix*" or "*suffix" is not. (I wish AWS documented this better.)

You could specify every IAM user you have in the bucket policy like so:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": [
        "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:user/alice",
        "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:user/bob",
        "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:user/carl",
        ...
        "arn:aws:iam::777777777777:user/zed",
}
```

But you probably don't want to update the policy for every new user.

It would be easiest to create an IAM group that grants access to that file. Then you would add all IAM users to that group. If you add new users then you'll have to manually add them to that group, so it is not as convenient as what you originally wanted.